# C++ member initialization list in anonymous union of structs

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, unions

I have the following class:

```
class LineSegW {
public:

    union {
        struct {
        public:
            int sx;
            int sy;
            int ex;
            int ey;
        };

        struct {
        public:
            Vec2i s;
            Vec2i e;
        };
    };

    int w;

    LineSegW(int _sx, int _sy, int _ex, int _ey, int _w) : 
        sx(_sx), sy(_sy), ex(_ex), ey(_ey), w(_w) {}
};
```

Vec2i consists simply of 2 integers. Now the problem is that the given constructor does not initialise the class members, except the integer w which is not in the union. When I write the constructor as

```
LineSegW(int _sx, int _sy, int _ex, int _ey, int _w) {
    sx = _sx;
    sy = _sy;
    ex = _ex;
    ey = _ey;
    w = _w;
}
```

everything works as expected. Both variants produce no warnings or errors so what is wrong with the first option?

Comment: No valid C++ (anonymous structures in a union)

Comment: vs2012 compiles without error or warning though

Comment: @testman That does not mean that it is in accordance with standard. As far as I know anonymous structs are not allowed by standard.

Comment: @Lehu Yes, it is apparently not standard, still the second example is non standard as well and works as expected. Why allow non standard when not being consistent with it... confusing

Comment: No compiler is perfect. Bugs and non-conformant behavior are constantly being found and corrected.

Comment: @JonHarper And sometimes non-conformant behaviour is intended. MS has even a list of purposeful "deviations" from standard.

Comment: @Lehu microsoft are still holding back the field of computer science even after the departure of the fat baboon?

Comment: @Lehu Compiler extensions are just extensions and are not portable. If you refer to MSVC's general quirkiness, well.. that's why you test with gcc and Clang for compatibility.